# Installer script to insert data from excel

Tags: magento-1.9

I am creating a module for Magento. For this I need already inserted data in table. For this I need to write sql/module_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php installer script to insert data from excel or csv to table.

my installer script is like this to create table

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();


$installer->run("

CREATE TABLE `{$this->getTable('module_setup_data')}` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `code` varchar(255),
  `code_type` varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    ");

$installer->endSetup();
```

Please guide me how to write sql/module_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php installer script to insert query from excel or csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the data in a separate directory called Data in the module directory, You can get the full tutorial on this [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/using-magento-1-6-data-install-scripts/) for using this method

For reading the data from csv, Magento has provided the class Varien_File_Csv, you can use it and read the data , you will get the data in an array,

For Reading the data from excel, you need to use some Third party Library, which i don't recommend for using only to insert data for one time.

Comment: For `module_setup_data` table I have not created any model or collection class. `$collection = Mage::getModel('module/setup_data')->getCollection()` is not working. So, Can you please guide me how can I get value from this table. Thanks buddy for your help

Comment: There is no module called "module", you need to define model first, the "module" will be replaced by your module name, and setup_data can be any model name associated with the table

Comment: I have not created any model which is associated with the table

Comment: You need to create the model, without that you can not do any database interaction, not even the installation of the module

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm)  for creating the model